# JQuery enqueue causing wordpress uncaught error

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Hi I am a beginner and creating simple wordpress template. Everything works except the code line in bold in my functions.php file (**wp_enqueue('jquery');**). When I exclude it the error goes away, but I don't see JQuery added by wordpress when I view sourcecode. Not sure if this is code issue or Jquery version issue. I tried adding JQuery migrate plugin and still same error. I am running all of this on local machine set up by Laragon. Below is my code and error. Appreciate any help.

**Here is my functions.php file:**

```
    <?php

function load_css(){
    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), false, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_css');


function load_js(){
     wp_enqueue('jquery');
     wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'jquery', false, true);
     wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
 }
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js');
```

**here is header.php file:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
<?php wp_head();?>
</head>
<body>
```

**here is footer.php file**

```
<?php wp_footer();?>
</body>
</html>
```

**here is front-page.php file**

```
<?php get_header();?>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

**error message:**
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_enqueue() in C:\laragon\www\test\wp-content\themes\SeanTheme\functions.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(287): load_js('') #1 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-includes\plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-includes\script-loader.php(2004): do_action('wp_enqueue_scri...') #4 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(287): wp_enqueue_scripts('') #5 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #6 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-includes\plugin.php(484): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #7 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-includes\general-template.php(3005): do_action('wp_head') #8 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-content\themes\SeanTheme\header.php(8): wp_head() #9 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-includes\template.php(730): require_once('C:\laragon\www\...') #10 C:\laragon\www\test\wp-includes\template in C:\laragon\www\test\wp-content\themes\SeanTheme\functions.php on line 13

Comment: As the error message states, `wp_enqueue(...);` (line 13 in your functions.php file) isn't a valid function name. It's (in this case) [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) :P

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be using `wp_register_style()` to register a **JS** file. That's what `wp_enqueue_script()` is for.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress automatically loads jQuery for you, if another script requires jquery simply specify it in the $deps parameter, when enqueuing your other JavaScript files. So remove wp_enqueue('jquery').

```
function load_js(){
     wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
 }
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js');
```

Comment: Thx much for the response and explanation @Phil